# Windows dual boot with Ubuntu as native OS

Tags: partitioning, windows, dual-boot

I want to put Windows 7 on my machine but I'm already using Ubuntu 12.04- most tutorials and advice I can find only describe **how to dual boot using Windows as the native OS**, which I do not want to..

- Is this because there will be problems creating a dual boot from inside Ubuntu?
- If so, what can I do?
- I am required to erase my Ubuntu partition? Installing first Windows and then Ubuntu?

Comment: See [How can I install Windows 7 after I've installed Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6317/how-can-i-install-windows-7-after-ive-installed-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

Well,it is generally advised to Install windows first since GRUB detects Windows. If you install windows later, the windows boot manager doesn't detect Ubuntu and automatically starts Ubuntu. But there is a solution.

Don't erase the Ubuntu partition. 
Create another partition for windows.
Install windows. 
Burn an iso of Ubuntu on a usb stick or a DVD.
After Installing windows boot ubuntu live session from the USB.

Boot from the live CD. Open the terminal

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update
```

-Press Enter - Then type:

```
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

Then open boot repair. Perform recommended repairs. This Will solve the problem and Show you Grub menu with the option of choosing either windows or Ubuntu. If that doesn't solve it(Which I highly doubt that it wouldn't solve your problem), paste the link provided from the boot repair here.